# Wicket - create a dynamic label

Tags: wicket

I would like to create a dynamic label in a wicket project.

I have the variable x, which is of type boolean. If the value is true, then the label should output "Text 1". Otherwise it should display "Text 2".

I don't want to set the value from the outside, but rather the label should know what kind of value it should display.

Which method do I have to override for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to override any method just put in the proper Model.

```
new Label("id", () -> x ? "Text 1" : "Text 2");
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Looks pretty. Unfortunately I have a longer query at one point. What is the correct syntax for a whole "block"? {} doesnt work.

Comment: The lambda used in the answer is just a short way to write: `new IModel<String>() {@Override public String get() {return ...}}`

Comment: That already works wonderfully. However, I now want to add an AjaxButton to a wicket page. Unfortunately the AjaxButton requires a form. However, I would like to add this on its own. Various newsgroups recommend using an AjaxLink, but using an input: button in the markup. That works wonderfully so far. However, I would now like to dynamically adjust the text of the button. Unfortunately, the following code does not work here: new AjaxLInk ("id", () -> x? "Text 1": "Text 2"); What would the correct implementation be? Is there a better way than override the value attribute on onComponentTag?

Comment: Please create new questions.